# Android. Как получить длину кривой

Tags: android

Есть кривая. Как можно получить ее длину?

```
 mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        mPath.moveTo(50, 50);
        mPath.cubicTo(x1,y1, x2,y2,x3,y3);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
```

Comment: а что вы понимаете под длиной кривой? Может есть смысл самому её обновлять при каждой операции рисования?

Comment: Длина кривой - число, которое  в математике обычно получают методом интегрирования функции кривой. Ровную линию можно измерить линейкой, как в android измерить длину нарисованой кривой?

Comment: @PeteGr сами отвечаете на свой вопрос, один из способов воспользоваться формулой длины криво через интеграл. у вас есть всё необходимое для подсчёта

Comment: @PeteGr вам нужно подставить в одну из [формул](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9) параметрическое уравнение кубической кривой безье и проинтегрировать от [0, 1]

Comment: Вообще то и линию безье можно нарисовать без андроид функций. Да и вообще Андроид тоже не нужен, можно и самому сделать свою операционную систему ))) ответ нашел. Есть специальная андроид функция которая возвращает длинну кривой ))